# Yii2 ActiveForm ajax validation callback

Tags: ajax, forms, yii2

Is there any way to get errors after ajax validation in js?
I need to create some custom modals with errors info. So i think i need some sort of callback function...

Any weird options, like binding submit event on form works bad, i can't get info about filling required fields, for example.

Comment: Please add the code and describe what you already have tried. Did you check official guide? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation

Comment: "Is there any way to get errors after ajax validation in js?" yes there is a way. Also read about how to ask proper questions

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActiveForm JavaScript API.

Example:

```
$('#form').on('afterValidate', function (event, fields, errors) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert('Errors exists');
    }
});
```